# Android Studio - Is it necessary to put all the images in flat structure?

Tags: image, android-studio, drawable

I want to add many images to my project.
As the best of my understanding, I can't use hierarchy location when importing my images.
What's the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Add those image in the folder named drawable in your app and then when you   use the image use `@drawable/image.png` in the XML file

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
My problem is that I have many images and the flat list is very long.